# DocumentDB .Net Client Library LINQ Aggregates Error

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I'm just getting started with DocumentDB and wanted to try out the aggregation features recently added. However, when I try to use them I get the following exception:
`Query expression is invalid, expression return type System.Int32 is unsupported. Query must evaluate to IEnumerable.`

I've already got a DocumentClient object, named `client` below.

```
var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId);
var options = new FeedOptions {MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true};

var count = client.CreateDocumentQuery<LogEvent>(collectionUri, options)
    .Where(f => f.Player == "SomePlayer")
    .Count();
```

I'm working against the local emulator. The collection has four documents in it.

Is this something that's just not available in the local emulator right now? Or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using .NET SDK 1.12.1? This is the version with support for LINQ aggregates

Comment: I have also tested your code with my Azure DocumentDB Emulator and found that when the version prior to 1.12.1 then I could encounter the same issue, while upgrade the version, then it could work as expected.

Comment: Just want to confirm that whether you could solve this issue after upgrading the version of your .NET SDK.

Comment: **100% fixed the issue.** I'm very unsure how I wound up with an older version of the client library, since I just installed the package for the first time only a couple of days before I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, I tested it against my Azure DocumentDB (instead of the local emulator), then I could encounter the same error as you provided:

[image]

As Aravind Ramachandran mentioned about the version, then I checked my installed version and found it was Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.11.4. After updating the version to 1.12.1 or the higher version, then I could retrieve the expected result.

Here is the [release notes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/changelog.md) of Azure DocumentDB for .NET as follows:

> **Changes in 1.12.1**
>
> Added LINQ support for aggregation queries (COUNT, MIN, MAX, SUM, and AVG).